# Case sensitive tab completion

Tags: pantheon-terminal, bash

I'm new to Elementary (though not to Linux) and really enjoying it so far. One thing I find annoying though is the case insensitive tab completion in the terminal/shell - I can see how it might be newbie friendly but I find it annoying :-) Is there a way to turn it off?

Cheers,
Andrew

Comment: Can you separate your question and answer (put the answer as an answer and accept it) so that it is available for future reference?

Comment: Done - sorry this is my first time using stack exchange!

Comment: It says I can only accept my own answer after two days - I'll set a reminder to accept it then :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And of course as soon as I ask I find the answer - set completion-ignore-case off in /etc/inputrc

(from https://askubuntu.com/questions/87061/can-i-make-tab-auto-completion-case-insensitive-in-the-terminal)